# Eclipse & Grade how to generate jar so that debugger can access the source code?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gradle

I am using Eclipse 4.20.0 with Gradle plugin. (Gradle version 6.6)
I have created a jar.
I have created another project that references this jar.
I want to debug the last project, but when a class from the jar is invoked, Eclipse displays the file with extension ".class", but cannot find the source file with extension ".java" and displays "Source not found" "The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Project and External Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries"

the build.gradle file for the project that creates the jar is:

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

java {
  withSourcesJar() //For including the sources??
}

// My customization
project.jar.destinationDirectory = file("$rootDir/../mytargets")  //Save jars in the same folder
project.archivesBaseName = 'a-annotations' //Set the name of the jar file
project.version = '1.0'

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}
```

The build.gradle for the project that uses this jar is

```
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
  id 'java-library-distribution'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

java {
  withSourcesJar() //For including the sources??
}

// My customization 
project.jar.destinationDirectory = file("$rootDir/../mytargets")  //Save jars in the same folder
project.archivesBaseName = 'p-if07-run' 
project.version = '1.0'
 
dependencies {
  // Use JUnit test framework.
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
  api files('../mytargets/a-annotations-1.0.jar')  // The jar !!!! 
}

// Collect all the dependencies into the folder "lib"
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'Execute',
      'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { 'lib/'+it.getName() }.join(' ')
    ) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, replacing the **jar** part of the **build.gradle** file with this one, solved my problem

```
jar {   
    from sourceSets.main.allSource  //Include java sources
}
```